# Getting the gcd from a string list of Fraction Denominators

Tags: python, list, greatest-common-divisor

This solved it.

> You're appending lists to dentemp ([s[x]]), and then trying to apply int on those lists. (May be you should drop the extra []) – hcwhsa 19 mins ago

I'm having trouble getting my list members to be able to be used as numbers to calculate the gcd in getgcd function.

Error I get now:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 51, in <module>
    getgcd()
  line 42, in getgcd
    deninttemp=list(map(int,dentemp))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

The code:

```
from fractions import gcd
frac=[]
flipfrac=[]
numtemp=[]
dentemp=[]
deninttemp=[]
lntemp=[]
ldtemp=[]

def insert():
    print("Enter your Fractions, Enter 0 when done.\n")
    while True:
        x=str(input())
        if x!="0":
            frac.append(x)
        elif x=="0":
            print("done")
            break

def store():
    for i in range(len(frac)):
        l=frac[i].find("/")
        lntemp.append(l)
        s=frac[i]
        for x in range(l):
            numtemp.append([s[x]])

    for v in frac:
        flip=v[::-1]
        flipfrac.append(flip)


    for i in range(len(flipfrac)):
        l=flipfrac[i].find("/")
        ldtemp.append(l)
        s=flipfrac[i]
        for x in range(l):
            dentemp.append([s[x]])


def getgcd():
    for i in range (len(dentemp)-1):
        deninttemp=list(map(int,dentemp))
        a=deninttemp[i]
        b=deninttemp[i+1]


insert()
store()
getgcd()
```

Comment: You're appending lists to `dentemp` (`[s[x]]`), and then trying to apply `int` on those lists. (May be you should drop the extra `[]`)

Comment: Have you tried list comprehension? Such: deninttemp = [int(i) for i in dentemp]

Comment: I think you are making this harder then it needs to be.  Comment your code so that we can see what you are wanting to accomplish with each step.

Comment: I did try list comprehension but removing the extra [] solved it, i most likely had something there before and removed it and forgot to get rid of the rest. Thank you everyone!